# CSS: Are negative margins needed here?

Tags: html, css

I'm practicing and getting to know how to use CSS. At the moment, I'm building a mock up of a youtube video page. I have 4 divs, one being the side bar, and the only way I can figure out how to get it positioned next to the video div and video-info div is through the use of negative margins. I feel like there is probably a better way, but I can't figure it out.

```css
/* nav-bar */

.nav-bar {
  background-color: green;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/* video */

.video {
  background-color: red;
  height: 360px;
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 100px;
}
/* video-info */

.video-info {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 640px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
/* sidebar */

.sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  height: 900px;
  width: 416px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-top: -525px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
</div>

<div class="video">
</div>

<div class="video-info">
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it already next to the video? The sidebar is on the right side and the video is on the left side. So they are next to eachother

Comment: You can obtain the same result with no negative margin if the floating `sidebar` element appears before the `video` and `video-info` elements in the HTML.

Comment: No, there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Thanks @Mumpo! Why is this though? All of the divs are block elements, so shouldn't the order not matter, and the next div start under the previous one no matter what?

Comment: It is because of how floating elements work. They stack up horizontally, so when you put a non-floated element like `video` after a floated one, it is placed vertically at the same starting point as `nav-bar`.